# Css sticky footer causing images not to fit in div

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">     
        body{
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        #content{
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            width: 60%;
            height: auto;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -30%;
            padding: 10px;
            z-index: 100;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        html, body {
            height: auto;
        }

        #wrap {
            min-height: 100%;
        }

        #main {
            overflow:auto;
            padding-bottom: 150px;
        }  /* must be same height as the footer */

        #footer {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
            height: 150px;
            clear:both;
        } 
        .instructions{
            margin-top: 50px;
            font-family: serif;
            font-size: medium;
            width: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -25%;
            position: relative;
            margin-bottom: 60px;
        }
        .repbanner{
            background-color: red;
            width: 108%;
            height: auto;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -54.5%;                
            margin-top: 40px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 200;
            border: 1px #a70000 solid;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            font-size: smaller;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            padding-top: 3px;
            padding-bottom: 3px;
        }

        .dembanner{
            background-color: blue;
            width: 108%;
            height: auto;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -54.5%;
            margin-top: 40px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 200;
            border: 1px navy solid;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            font-size: smaller;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            padding-top: 3px;
            padding-bottom: 3px;

        }
        .introbanner{
            background-color: white;
            width: 108%;
            height: auto;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -54.5%;
            margin-top: 40px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 199;
            border: 1px gray solid;
            text-align: center;
            color: black;
            font-size: smaller;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin-bottom: 10px;

        }

        /*Opera Fix*/
        body:before {
            content:"";
            height:100%;
            float:left;
            width:0;
            margin-top:-32767px;/
        }
        #animals{
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            height: auto;
        }
        .animalmugshot{
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }
        img{
            position: relative
        }
    </style>
    <!--[if !IE 7]>
        <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
        </style>
    <![endif]-->

    </head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
        <div class="repbanner">
            INTRODUCTION
        </div>
        <div class="instructions">
        Hello and thanks for using the Chrome extension Political Animals. Below are the instructions on how the piece works. Enjoy!
        <br/>
        <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="dembanner">
            Instructions
        </div>
            <div class="instructions">
                Here's how the project works!

                1. Surf the Web. Try any website you would like.
                2. You should be redirected to a news site. Do not be alarmed!
                3. Enjoy!
            </div>  
            <div class="introbanner">
            Meet the Cast
            </div>

            <div id="animals">
                <div class="animalmugshot">
                <img src="animalshots/thumbnails/PoliticalAnimal.png" alt="Charlie the CEO"/><br/><p>Charlie the CEO</p>
                </div>
                <div class="animalmugshot">
                <img src="animalshots/thumbnails/PoliticalFox.png" alt="Freddy the Financial Agent"/>
                <br/>
                <p> Freddy the Financial Agent</p>
                </div>
                <div class="animalmugshot">
                <img src="animalshots/thumbnails/PoliticalGiraffe.png" alt="Geoffry the Graphic Designer"/>
                <br/>
                <p>Geoffry the 
                <br/>Graphic Designer</p>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">

</div>
</body>
```

The div " animals" and "animalmugshots" should be in the "wrapper" and "content" but for some reason, the animals spill over the white "content" body part. I am confused as to why? Hopefully someone can help me out!

Comment: Because your pictures are styled with floats, their height is not considered in the auto height without a clearfix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element, `#animals`, was collapsing upon itself as the children element were being floated.

Floated and absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the flow of the document, therefore causing the parent element(s) to collapse with undefined dimensions.

Adding a defined height to the parent element, or `overflow:hidden` will solve this collapsing issue.

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/Q3AXh/) - made the footer black for visibility purposes.

```
#animals {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;       /* Added this.. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to clear your floats in `#animals` or all divs

```
div:after //OR
#animals:after {
    display: table;
    content: '';
    clear: both;  
}
```